# Synapse automatically converting ISO date string argument yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss into mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am trying to run spark job using a Synapse pipeline by passing timestamp as command line argument. Before the code runs related to spark job, synapse is converting the string command line argument value from ISO format 2019-04-25T09:00:00 to 04/25/2019 09:00:00 somehow and it's throwing error because my spark code is designed to parse the dates only in ISO format.

Does anyone know why or how synapse is converting the timestamp argument. How to make the synapse pass the command line argument to spark code as is.

Also I see from I/p for spark jobs from synapse/monitor UI section that synapse adds Z (2019-04-25T09:00:00Z) at the end of the argument.

Error stdout Driver: Text '04/25/2019 09:00:00' could not be parsed at index 0

I tried to pass only 2019-04-25and it sill fails saying Text '04/25/2019' could not be parsed at index 10

Pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rj7K.png)

Spark Job: Doesn't have any command line arguments(they are only passed through pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's not reading the timestamp correctly.
Try casting it in the command line like so:

```
toTimestamp('2019-04-25T09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss')
```

[image]